# What is the translation of "Papillarleistenspuren"?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

What is the translation of "Papillarleistenspuren"?

I couldn't find the translation of  "Papillarleistenspuren".
So please help me!

The concrete context is

> "Adam is befähigt, Gutachten über **Papillarleistenspuren** zu erstatten.
>   "

Comment: »Papillarleistenspuren« is already a German word. Or do you want to translate it into another language? This is off-topic here, because you would need the expertise of a language different from German to translate it. And: You didn't say into which language you want it to be translated. French? Russian? Japanese?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Es dürfte offensichtlich sein, was der Frager möchte.  Er will wissen, was das Wort bedeutet. Deswegen auf der Formulierung seiner Frage rumzureiten, finde ich ein bißchen erbsenzählerisch. *Translation* umfasst auch die Übersetzung eines Wortes in ein verständlicheres Wort derselben Sprache.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast What is the translation of "Papillarleistenspuren" in english? You can see the tags! german-to-english

Comment: @tofro Das is m.E. nicht so offensichtlich. Es könnte sehr wohl sein, das dem Frager die Bedeutung des Worts bekannt ist, und er nach einer möglichst äquivalenten Übersetzung ins Englische sucht. Bei dem Wort und dem Beispielsatz schwingt mehr mit als nur simpel _"Fingerabdrücke"_. Ich habe schon zu viele schlecht übersetzte Bücher gelesen :3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fingerprints**

*Papillarleisten* are the characteristic lines that everyone has on hands, fingers, and feet. And *Spuren* are the traces left by them. So, the word is just a more complicated term for *Fingerabdrücke*.

(Also it is more precise - people tend to create prints with more than fingers)

In case you want a 1:1 literal translation to scientific English, you might want to use

> dermal papillae traces

or

> papillary ridge traces

(from [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=gbHMAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT140#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Comment: The more common German word for this is **Fingerabdrücke**.

Comment: @Janka Sure, but _Papillarleistenspuren_ sounds more scientific.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: nun ja, sogar in der [Daktyloksopie](https://www.bka.de/DE/UnsereAufgaben/Ermittlungsunterstuetzung/Erkennungsdienst/Historie/historie.html) spricht man, wie auch in Gesetzen, fast nur von *Fingerabdrücken*.

Comment: @Takkat Das dürfte daran liegen, dass man die letzten 100 Jahre auch tatsächlich nur die Abdrücke von Fingern zur Identifikation verwendet hat. Handflächen- (inzwischen gängig) und Fussabdrücke (eher nicht so gängig, da die Mörder so selten barfuß gehen), werden erst seit ca. 15 Jahren aufgenommen und gespeichert. Da muß die Begrifflichkeit noch nachziehen. Ob aber *Papillarleistenspuren* das Potential hat, *Fingerabdrücke* zu ersetzen, muss sich wohl erst noch zeigen ...

Comment: @tofro es ist wohl eher der genetische Fingerabdruck, der eine Präzisierung verlangen könnte.

Comment: *Papillarleistenspuren* ist ein Überbegriff. Fingerabdrücke sind zwar die häufigsten, aber nicht die einzigen.

Comment: @Takkat: Naja, Gr. *daktylos* bedeutet ja auch Finger. <g>

Comment: @Rudy Ich glaube der Fokus hat sich mit/nach meiner Antwort etwas "verschoben".

Answer (score 2):

While in english the common term used would be ***Fingerprints*** (as [@tofro's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/43655/28897) already pointed out), the more close word by word translation into english would be

> **Papillary ridge traces**

preserving the *papilla* term.

So the translation of your sentence keeping semantics as close as possible could be

> "Adam is qualified to provide expert reports about papillary ridge traces."

I am not an editor or lector though.